# differentiable structure on mobius strip

Tags: differential-geometry

Define $M= \mathbb{R}^2/\sim$ where $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ if $x-x'=2n$ for some integer $n$ and $y = (-1)^n y'$.

Then how can I give a differentiable sturucture on $M$? Is there a general technique for this?

(Currently I'm reading Lee's SM. I hope you give me some ref. pages too.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a unique differential structure on $M$ such that the quotient map $p:\mathbb R^2\to M$ is locally a diffeomorphism. You can construct charts using the fact that $p$ is a covering map.

More generally, if $M$ is a smooth manifold and $p:M\to N$ is a covering, then $N$ has a unique smooth structure such that $p$ is locally a diffeomorphism.

This is a good exercise!

Comment: Could you help me with the explicit construction part using $p$'s covering property?

Comment: I could but I think you should do it yourself. I suggest you review the definition of what a covering map is if you do not have that fresh and then try to do this. As I wrote, this is a very good exercise.

Comment: Okay. But just one more question (I'm very new to this DG and I'm not reading the book in order). Do I have to use the covering map $\epsilon:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{S}^1$ to construct an atlas on $M$?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$